# Bulk User profile updates using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, user-profile, active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I have an Active Directory sync app which is using for internal purpose and its saving the data to SQL table feeding from Azure AD via Graph API. Along with its basic functionality, we are updating custom user profile properties using CSOM. But most of the time after some request processing, we are getting Error 429, Too many requests.

Is there any option of bulk update  to update a set of (say 500/1000 profile) custom user profile properties in a single request? Please help me on this. If there is any other option, please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may get throttled. You could refer to this documentation: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-avoid-getting-throttled-or-blocked-in-sharepoint-online

When we get throttled, SharePoint Online returns HTTP status code 429 ("Too many requests") or 503 ("Server Too Busy") and the requests will fail.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have already gone thorugh this link, my issues is, I have around 8 Lakh records and I am doing the SP User profiles updates as a batch. Each batch will process 24000 records. at that time i am facing this issue